# UIView subclass (Swift4) - custom method (setNumber) not working as expected

Tags: swift, uiview, subclass

I've created a subclass of UIView called UIBingoBall to display a bingo ball (see below).  I've left out the init's for brevity - but the class works as-is.  I can instantiate it, set the 3 properties "myimage, myLetterLabel and myNumberLabel" and see the correct bingo ball.

But - I'm trying to add a method to the class called .setNumber(ballNumber: Int) which will change the 3 properties of the ball appropriately - all in one step - but when I do so, it's only partially working.  It's changing the image and displaying the image correctly.  It's changing the label text - but it's not displaying it.
If I change the values individually (instead of calling the function), it all works fine.

Can somebody please have a quick look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Or explain why the behavior is different?

Here is the function I would like to use:

```
func setNumber(ballNumber: Int) {if ballNumber > 75 || ballNumber < 1 { return }

    let fontModifier = frame.height / 70
    let ballLetter:Int = (ballNumber - 1) / 15
    self.myLetterLabel.text = bingoLetterArray[ballLetter]
    self.myNumberLabel.text = "\(ballNumber)"
    self.myimage.image = bingoBallImageArray[ballLetter]
    self.myNumberLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontModifier / 24, weight: .heavy)
    self.myLetterLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontModifier / 8, weight: .heavy)

}
```

Here are the property definitions:

```
class UIBingoBall: UIView {

private let bingoBallImageArray: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "BingoBlankB"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "BingoBlankI"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "BingoBlankN"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "BingoBlankG"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "BingoBlankO")]
private let bingoLetterArray: [String] = ["B", "I", "N", "G", "O"]


var myimage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BlankBallB")
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.backgroundColor = .clear
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()

var myLetterLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "B"
    label.textColor = .blue
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8, weight: .bold)
    return label
}()

var myNumberLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "1"
    label.textColor = .blue
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .heavy)
    return label
}()
```

And, in case they're necessary, here is my setupViews() that I call from init.

```
func setupViews() {
    addSubview(myimage)
    addSubview(myLetterLabel)
    addSubview(myNumberLabel)

    myimage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myimage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    myimage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    myimage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    myNumberLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myimage.centerYAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
    myNumberLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myimage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myLetterLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myNumberLabel.topAnchor,constant: -8).isActive = true
    myLetterLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
    myLetterLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myimage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

Thanks in advance to any who can (and do) try to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in font

```
let fontModifier = frame.height / 70

self.myNumberLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontModifier / 24, weight: .heavy)
self.myLetterLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontModifier / 8, weight: .heavy)
```

it's value may be set to 0 , frame height should be multiple of 70*24 = 1680 to give 1 for the label's font size which for sure is not predictable

Comment: Yep.  Good catch!  The font was the problem. I know that in a 70pt frame, the number font should be 24 - so I tried to make the font increase/decrease relative to the size of the frame it's put in.  
I should have been multiplying the fontModifier by 24 instead of dividing it.  Font ended up being set to 0.04 in my 80pt frame... stupid, stupid, stupid...
Working now.  Thank you.